# Get Ajax call data in html page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call to an html page and sending a parameter with it. How can I get the parameter which I sent in the ajax call in html page?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demopage.html",
    data: {"id":"0"},
    headers: { 'authtoken': $.jStorage.get("token") },
    success:sucesscallbackmethod,
    error: function(data,status) {
        alert("Error  "+status);
    }
});
```

Comment: you have unbalanded brackets in the code

Comment: why is it down voted??

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to "capture" the parameter in the destination page? I mean in the "demopage.html"?

Comment: yes i want to capture the value of "id" in "demopage.html" this call is made from another html page

Comment: you must send the ajax to a server side file (demopage.php or demopage.asp), only a server may "capture" and process sent parameters

Answer (score 0):

This simplest way :)

```
 var parameter = "0"; 

    $.ajax({
                url: "demopage.html",
                data: {"id": parameter},
                headers: { 'authtoken': $.jStorage.get("token") },
                success:sucesscallbackmethod,
                error: function(data,status) {
                    alert("Error  "+status);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: how to get the value of parameter in the html page??

Comment: You can use global variable to see this parameter in the all page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the way to read the parameter id 's value from the demopage.html , Using html you can't do this.. You will have to use a serverside language such as php or jso to read this value.
 eg: from php you can read the value by calling `$_GET['id']`

Or if you just want to pass a value between two html pages you can always use WebStorage.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
//store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve    
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```